# SQL query - how to get counts in table

Tags: sql

I have a table X that has column called version that has 4-5 values in it example 1,2,3,4,5

If the column value is 1 or 3 then I am good, else it's and error

### question

what is the query so that I want output like this

Total # of values  |  Total good i.e. value is (1,3) | total failed i.e value not in (1,3)

Can someone please help me with the query

Comment: I did wrong - I am trying to count the values separately in separate queries and then using them...as counts...but I want to get everything in one sql statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select count(*) as TotalValues
  , (select count(*) from test where id in(1, 3)) as TotalGood
  , (select count(*) from test where id not in (1, 3)) as TotalFailed
from test
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff90b/6)

Based on your comment, if you need the percentage you would use this:

```
SELECT TotalValues
  , TotalGood
  , TotalFailed
  , Cast(TotalGood as decimal(10, 2))/Cast(TotalValues as decimal(10, 2)) as PercentGood
FROM 
(
  select count(*) as TotalValues
    , (select count(*) from test where id in(1, 3)) as TotalGood
    , (select count(*) from test where id not in (1, 3)) as TotalFailed
  from test
) x
```

Comment: Also how do I calculate % of TotalGood from this same query

Comment: @bluefeet  -  Also how do I calculate % of TotalGood from this same query –